# Ionic Printing http response

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to print my response but get the error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'HttpEvent<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type 'string'.
(parameter) res: HttpEvent<any>
```

the block of code to do this is:

```
 post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {

    let observable = this.http.post<any>(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, reqOpts).share();

    observable.subscribe(res => {
      this.core.log(res);
    }, err => {
      this.core.log(err);
      this.core.toast("server err " + err);
    });

    return observable;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question like this: You make a http request and want to print the response from this request?!

To do this:

```
   post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
    this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, reqOpts).subscribe(res => {
      this.core.log(res); //here you can return the result
      //return result
    }, err => {
      this.core.log(err);
      this.core.toast("server err " + err);
    });

    }
```

Comment: I get this error

[ts] Argument of type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
(parameter) res: ArrayBuffer

Comment: Maybe your `endpoint` isnt a string. Check that your endpoint parameter is a string